# How to extract those tags as list using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautiful Soup.

Could you help me extacting those tags from this html:

```
<p class="entry-tags">
    <span class="entry-tags-inner">
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-10165">Tag1</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-29555">Tag2</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-10169">Tag3</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-24312">Tag4</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-23324">Tag5</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

I tried this:

```
tags = soup.findAll('span', class_='entry-tags-inner')
lines = [span.get_text() for span in tags]
print(lines)
```

but I get a string.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `<span>` has the text of all its children. To get each `<a>`'s text as a separate element in a list, then use `soup.findAll('a', class_='entry-tag')` instead to get all `<a>` tags with the `entry-tag` class. Like this:

```
import bs4


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''
<p class="entry-tags">
    <span class="entry-tags-inner">
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-10165">Tag1</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-29555">Tag2</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-10169">Tag3</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-24312">Tag4</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-23324">Tag5</a>
    </span>
</p>
                         ''', 'html.parser')

tags = soup.findAll('a', class_='entry-tag')
lines = [span.get_text() for span in tags]
print(lines)
```

Comment: @AlexanderVarovsky Happy to help! If my answer/explanation best helped you, then consider marking it as correct to indicate that it worked for you. It would also help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

findAll will return a list

in this case u can use this :

```
tags = soap.findAll('a', class_='entry-tag')
for tg in tags:
    print(tg.text)
```

Comment: @AlexanderVarovskyno problem i am glad to helping you if this answer help you you can also help me by kilick my answer as a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding to my comment and just in addition to the other both answers - Using a [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) you could select your elements more comfortable and better readable. This one selects all `<a>` in the element with `class` named `entry-tags-inner`

```
soup.select('.entry-tags-inner a')
```

with `list comprehension` it look like this:

```
[a.get_text() for a in soup.select('.entry-tags-inner a')]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<p class="entry-tags">
    <span class="entry-tags-inner">
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-10165">Tag1</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-29555">Tag2</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-10169">Tag3</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-24312">Tag4</a>
        <a href="#" class="entry-tag entry-tag-23324">Tag5</a>
    </span>
</p>''')

[a.get_text() for a in soup.select('.entry-tags-inner a')]
```

###### Output

```
['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5']
```